# Stripe Connect - link with locale

Tags: api, hyperlink, stripe-payments, translate

I am using API stripe Connect OAuth Reference (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts)

The link to redirect user is: 
    https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CODE&scope=read_write

It works perfectly. Landing page is : 
[image]

How can I translate this page?
I have tried using in url: `?locale=fr` but not working.
I could not find anything in the documentation
Thanks

Comment: 6 years later, and I am wondering the same thing! Did you ever get an answer on this? Otherwise, I will contact Stripe shortly.

Comment: I tried also. No answers..

Comment: I got an answer on the #stripe channel on freenode: "the language depends on the country selected". There is no way of setting it.

Comment: I have also search every were there is no any kind of setting or url param for local, You need to manually change local from connect page's footer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a two-letter country code `stripe_user[country]` ([docs link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request)).

> Two-letter country code (e.g., US or CA).

For example:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&scope=read_write&stripe_user[product_description]=...&stripe_user[email]=john@gmail.com&stripe_user[url]=http://example.com/users/1234&stripe_user[first_name]=John&stripe_user[last_name]=Deere&stripe_user[business_name]=John%20Deere&stripe_user[country]=FR
```

Comment: This prefills the users' country, not the page's locale